# Javascript file placed in external file not executing

Tags: javascript, html, file

I made a webpage that inputs user's feedback using a form. On successful submit I display a thank you message on the same page, for which I'm using javascript.

The code executes well when I put the javascript on the same page. However, when I tried to separate the script onto a file (in a test webserver), it stopped executing.

Can you please help?

Relevant codes are mentioned below:
Head Element

```
<head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <!-- For proper rendering and touch zooming in mobile devices -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="images/logo.ico" />

        <title><?= htmlspecialchars($title) ?></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/pure/0.6.0/pure-min.css" />
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />      
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../javascript/submit-logic.js"></script>

    </head>
```

First 2-3 lines of the javascript function:

```
$(function () 
{
    $('form').submit(function (e) 
    {                   
        e.preventDefault();
```

Detailed code (HTML, CSS, Javascript) can be found in my codepen (this is working as expected) : http://codepen.io/abbor123/pen/YGwVXg

Javascript folder is placed outside the Public folder and has 755 permission.

**Edit 1:**

**File Tree Screenshot**:

[image: File Tree]

**Console Error Screenshot**: (submit-logic.js is the name of my javascript file. The URL mentioned on hovering over this link is: /javascript/submit-logic.js:1 )

[image: Console Error]

The javascript code page is available at the following URL:
https://gist.github.com/abor123/3193eb399c3f973be453ae9a8fcc0ce5

Comment: Right now we can only assume that you above your root (where index.html is) you have a folder named 'javascript' in which your js file resides. It would be helpful if you could provide a file-tree of your files.

Comment: As @Chewtoy said, its not really clear what's the problem. Can you check your browser console for any errors. Its possible it can't load the file, or is getting a 500 error on the server, either of which would help debug.

Comment: "Javascript folder is placed outside the Public folder" — I'd be surprised if your server was configured to serve static files that weren't in the Public folder given that such a folder exists.

Comment: Hello @Aeolingamenfel, I've updated the question above with details of file tree and console log error. Can you please suggest me on the reason of such an error? ....

Comment: Hello @Chewtoy, the question has been updated with necessary details. Please look into it.

Comment: @Quentin Please forgive my ignorance, but other php files are also present outside the public_html folder and they are not showing any sign of error, except the javascript folder. Can then folder permissions result in an error?

Comment: @ABor it looks like your Javascript *is* loading, but it has a bug that is causing it to error and not run fully.

Comment: @Aeolingamenfel Can you please look into that? Initially when I only had a single HTML file with the javascript code embedded in it, the code was running fine. Only when I separated different components of the file did the javascript stopped running.

Comment: @ABor are you using some sort of Javascript minifier or compiler?

Comment: That error is quite confusing. I'm not all that used to jQuery, but isn't that `$(function(){` supposed to end with a `()` ? Eg `$(function(){ /*code*/})();` ?

Comment: That error implies the server isn't giving back the Javascript that you linked us to. Its possible your server is throwing an error or is outputting HTML instead, and thus the error about the `<` character.

Comment: @Aeolingamenfel I've no idea what Javascript minifier is. Also when I click the link in the error shown in the console log, it open up the following HTML code, which happens to be that of the server and not mine. The HTML is pasted on the following URL for your reference: [https://gist.github.com/abor123/dbba75c7c9eef2f1376122d1a6e11db9]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move your javascript folder into public_html. As Quentin commented, your server likely isn't set up to serve any files outside public_html.

Comment: Moving the javascript folder to public_html worked. But I cannot understand why the php files outside public_html works and not the javascript. Can you please make me understand this? @Quentin

Comment: The non-public PHP files are never requested by the browser. They are only used by PHP itself.

Comment: To elaborate on @Quentin's point, PHP runs *server-side*, meaning it theoretically has access to the entire server (that you have given it permission to), meaning it can access things outside of the public root. Apache/Nginx/etc. restricts client access to the folders and files under  your document root, for security reasons, so anything that has to be loaded by the browser has to be accessible there.

Comment: Quentin and Aeolingamenfel are correct. The publicly facing PHP scripts are including or requiring files on a server level. The HTML being rendered by your browser however can only access publicly facing files and URL's.